# layer 0 vs layer 1 blockchain main blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I want to ask here a fundamental question about the difference between layer 0 and layer 1 for my understanding. i have read you can create main blockchains on layer 1 which lacks scaling. while the layer 2 are mostly side chains facilitating layer 1. while layer 0 are also main blockchains facilitating scalability and interoperability .

1. layer 1 is the main blockchain
2. layer 0 is also the main blockchain
3. layer 2 are sidechains

My question is that layer 0 and layer 1 will be called main blockchains?

my second question is that while initially creating blockchain the first question we must decide is that on which layer our blockchain will be layer 0 or layer 1?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that layer 0 and layer 1 will be called main
> blockchains?

You are right both layer 0 and layer 1 are main blockchains but the basic difference between them is that **layer 1** is a standalone blockchain which lacks scaling and is isolated from other blockchains they have all the functionalities on single chain while on the other hand **layer 0** acts as relay between different chains through which different chains can communicate hence provides scaling.

Bitcoin and Ethereum are examples of layer1 blockchains and Polkadot and Cosmos are examples of layer 0 blockchains.

> my second question is that while initially creating blockchain the
> first question we must decide is that on which layer our blockchain
> will be layer 0 or layer 1?

For creating an new blockchain it totally depends on your use case, if you want to act as a hub for different blockchains than go for layer 0. If you want a standalone blockchain than go for layer 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of blockchain technology, layer 0, layer 1, and layer 2 refer to different levels of the blockchain stack. Layer 0 is the underlying physical layer that deals with the hardware and network infrastructure. Layer 1 is the main blockchain layer that directly handles transactions and smart contracts. Layer 2 is a higher-level layer that provides additional functionality to layer 1, such as scaling solutions and interoperability.

To answer your first question, both layer 0 and layer 1 can be considered main blockchains. Layer 0 is often referred to as the "base layer" of the blockchain, while layer 1 is the primary layer for processing transactions and executing smart contracts.

Regarding your second question, the decision of which layer to build a blockchain on depends on various factors, such as the project's requirements, technical capabilities, and goals. In some cases, building a blockchain on layer 0 may be the best choice for scalability and interoperability, while in other cases, layer 1 may be more appropriate for handling transactions and smart contracts. It ultimately depends on the specific needs of the project.